# django-pytest with user-agent cant find request.user-agent

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

thanks for your time.

i've got a app thats getting tested with pytest-django. although i've been facing some issues for the request function o views.py.

at my views i've got some statements based on the request.user_agent(app installed django-user-agents) to select if will be displayed a mobile or desktop template. And those are getting me errors on
pytest-django.

views.py:

```
def curriculo_view(request):
    context = {}
    if request.user_agent.is_mobile:
        return render(request, 'amp/Curriculo-mobile.html', context)
    elif request.user_agent.is_pc:
        return render (request, 'admin/Curriculo.html', context)
    else:
        return render (request, 'admin/Curriculo.html', context)
```

test_views.py:

```
    def test_curriculo_view(self):
        path = reverse('curriculo')
        request =  RequestFactory().get(path)
        response = views.curriculo_view(request)
        assert response.status_code == 200
```

error:

```
    def curriculo_view(request):
        context = {}
>       if request.user_agent.is_mobile:
E       AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user_agent'

accounts\views.py:98: AttributeError
```

i've tried to set like when i want to set a user (ex:`request.user = User.objects.get()`), tried to set to the key of request.META['USER_AGENT'] and none is getting me trough this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`django-user-agents` uses middleware to attach user agent info to a request instance, but you are testing your view by directly calling it thus bypassing normal Django's request processing flow. Use django-pytest's `client` fixture instead to call you view by its path, for example:

```
def test_linux_chromium(client):
    path = reverse('curriculo')
    response = client.get(path,
                          HTTP_USER_AGENT='Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36')
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

Comment: it worked !! although i'm not understanding how the test fixtures works. i've tried with just client.get(path) and worked also; i've put the database mark but when i try to call an object it returns me a object with all fields Null. do you recommend any doc or tutorial?